# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in "Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php"

Tags: php, laravel

I have a congress details page and the user can access this page without being authenticated. This page has this link:

```
<a href="{{route('congress.show', ['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">More congress details</a>
```

And has this route:

```
Route::get('/congress/{id}/{slug?}', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@show',
    'as'   =>'congresses.show'
]);
```

In this congress details this page there are some details of a congress and below a form for the user select the quantities that he wants for each congress ticket  type. After the user select the quantities he goes to the registration page (registration.blade.php) and its returned an array with the selected quantities by the user to this registration.blade.php.

But for the user access the registration page he should be authenticated, so there is this route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
        Route::post('/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
        'uses' => 'RegistrationController@storeQuantity',
        'as'   =>'congresses.registration'
    ]);
  }
```

So when user click in "`<a href="{{route('congress.show', ['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">More congress details</a>`"  , in the congress details page, if the user is not authenticated he goes to the login page "http://layout.test/login".

After the user login it appears an error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

No message in "Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php"
```

Do you know how to correct the error?

Context flow:

[image]

**LoginController:**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a route set up for the url '/home'?

Comment: I have this route: "Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@index',
    'as'   =>'home'
]);
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is being caused because you're originally trying to post to `/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration` but if they are not logged in, they are redirected to your `login` form.

When they log in they are redirected to the intended page which would be `/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration` but this is a `POST` method, but at this point, Laravel will be redirecting you to this page as a `GET`.

Ideally you should change your code around so the submit buttons don't show until the user is logged in. You may also want to provide them a button to log in in place of the buy button.

Also on a different note, you may wish to change your 'default' `redirectTo` property to `/` if you do not have a `/home` route.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to have the select quantities form in the congress details page, and is necessary to have the POST method to collect the selected quantities from the user so I dont know how the code can be changed to maitain the same context. Maybe a solution could be  dont allow unauthenticated users access the congress details page  or have the selected quantities form in the registration page, but dont seems a good solution. Do you know some solution to maintain the selected quantities in the congress details page?

Comment: The only real way I think would to store them in the session (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session) before you get them to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do not exist route /home

Please create

```
Route::get('/home', [ 
  'uses' => 'HomeController@homeAction'
]);
```

Comment: I don't see how this'd solve the problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ceejayoz Because after logging in there is a redirect to the rout / home. Which, as the error shows, does not exist

Comment: That's not going to cause a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` exception, though.

Comment: It would only go there if the intended redirect wasn't set.